# Delete dot file only if non-dot file exists in *nix

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, filesystems

I'm moving files from a FAT32 filesystem into an EXFAT filesystem on a Mac. My understanding is that FAT32 doesn't support extended file attributes so it created dot files for each file.

However now that I've copied everything into an exFAT filesystem, I'd like to delete these dot files. Is there a way to copy a dot file but only if a non-dot file exists in the same directory (this way I can avoid deleting dot files that are config files).

This would be on a Mac CLI.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easy enough (eg `for f in .*; do [ -e "${f#.}" ] && rm "$f"; done`), but beware of a clash: on Ubuntu I have created files without realising that there is an equivalent file with a `.` prefix and there is no problem, but I don't know what would happen on a Mac FAT disc.

Answer (score 1):

Create an executable shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dotfile ; do
    path=${dotfile%/.*}
    name=${dotfile##*/.}
    if [[ -f $path/$name ]] ; then
        rm "$dotfile"
    fi
done
```

Then run from the top of the directory you want to clear:

```
find -name '.*' -exec rm-dotfiles.sh {} +
```

Where `rm-dotfiles.sh` is name of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a dot-file only if the matching non-dot-file exists is the same thing as removing the matching dot-file for all non-dot-files. So:

```
for f in *; do rm -f ".$f"; done
```

Note that the `*` above normally only matches non-dot-files, unless you have done `shopt -s dotglob` (in which case it is best reset before issuing the command).

A directory-recursive version would be:

```
for f in $(find -type f -name '[^.]*');do rm -f "$(dirname $f)/.$(basename $f)";done
```

(the name pattern in `find` excludes dot files)

Comment: How can I make this also check all subfolders?

Comment: See edited answer